# Conventions for a module that's part C, part Lua

Tags: lua

In my application most modules aren't pure Lua, or pure C, but hybrid.

I wonder what's the recommended "layout" for such modules.

So far I've found two approaches:

1. The [posix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix) module uses the name "posix_c" for the C module. Users aren't supposed to use this module. The Lua module, simply named "posix", imports (and augments) this module.
2. The [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) window manager exports the C part of the module to the global namespace. Since this name isn't in `package.loaded`, the Lua module can have the same name.

What is the method you recommend? Are there other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users aren't supposed to use something then it should be hidden: either in registry or completely hidden in Lua module's upvalue. That's for calls from Lua to C. For calls from C to Lua the only option is registry, but it can be used in non-conflicting ways if needed, as described below.

Since it's your app you can simply rely on registry itself. In my apps I register internal C functions in it and also assign Lua callbacks there from Lua side. E.g. one of things my Lua core scripts start with is `local internal = debug.getregistry()`. When all core scripts are loaded I can do sandboxing, disabling access of regular scripts to debug library etc.

In case you want to make a stand-alone module I'd suggest doing a C module that would call Lua script when loaded, passing the "hidden" table to it. For calls from C to Lua, C code can use address of any variable in the module as light userdata key to store the "hidden" table in registry.

Comment: Thanks. It's not the answer I was waiting for but I guess there's no "correct" answer. I finally chose the technique the `posix` module uses.